# Waterfall Model and Modified Waterfall Model

Tags: waterfall

What is the difference between Waterfall model and Modified Waterfall Model when it comes to software development processes?

It is said that the Modified Waterfall Model has overcome the shortcomings of Waterfall Model. But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified Waterfall model has slight difference comparing with traditional waterfall model, When we are considering as software development methodology. .

Waterfall model contains certain steps .

1>Requirements gathering   +(Verification and Validation phase(Modified Waterfall model))

2>Design (UFX and UI Team)+(Verification and Validation phase(Modified Waterfall model))

3>Coding(Development)   +(Verification and Validation phase(Modified Waterfall model))

4>QA(Testing)   +(Verification and Validation phase(Modified Waterfall model))

5>Maintenance  +(Verification and Validation phase(Modified Waterfall model))

"Verification and Validation phases" are add on in Modified Waterfall model .